# Music history learning software/website

Tags: web-apps, music, desktop-client

Has anyone heard/used a website or a desktop program to learn the history of music? With timelines, articles, pieces (extracts) like symphonies, concertos, etc. I am interested in times where our great composers lived (Mozart, Beethoven, etc.) - from several hundred years ago to something like these days, although I'm not that curious about composers of last decades.

As far as the software has a music history learning tool, I would be happy (I do not care much about other additional stuff, like knowledge tests, basically I don't need it - I would use the software to build and improve my knowledge). Regarding OS, this is not a factor of choosing either as I could switch. I just think that there is no such software outside.

Comment: What features should it provide? Are there other requirements (e.g. interactivity, knowledge tests)? Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: It sounds like you want a music history encyclopedia. So I have this question: What features do you need that could not be provided by a book? (I am not trying to ridicule your question, I am just trying to understand what you want). Thanks! :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - Thanks for the question. The answer is in your question! :) I'd like to find a digital alternative to a printed book. What regards music, cannot fully be covered in written form. Much must be listened. If you have a reference to a music piece, even knowing that something is very special in it, one may not be able to find it only by himself. Also, those pieces are often long. So it is not time-efficient to go through them unsupervised. A nice example: https://www.khanacademy.org/humanities/music/music-masterpieces-old-new/ludwig-van-beethoven-music/v/ludwig-van-beethoven-part-1

Comment: Could you please calculate the website/webapp score of your dream solution as explained at https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/219/140 and post the result here? Thanks :-)